# Uploading Base64 encoded image to server - 400 Server Error

Tags: android, image, encoding, base64

I'm uploading Base64 encoded image to the [HelpScout server](https://developer.helpscout.com/mailbox-api/endpoints/conversations/attachments/delete/) with JSON payload using Volley. This return in **com.android.volley.ServerError** and **status code 400**. I'm encoding the image as below:

```
var imageEncoded = ""
            try {
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context?.contentResolver, uri)
                //val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path)
                val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream)
                val imageBytes = stream.toByteArray()
                imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

I already have checked several questions asked but got no luck. Below is Volley method I'm working with:

```
public static void volleyRowJsonPostRequest(Context context,String url, JSONObject object,final Map<String, String> headers, final VolleyTaskListener taskListener) {
        final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            taskListener.onTaskComplete(response.toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null)
                            taskListener.onTaskFailed(networkResponse.statusCode);

                    }
                }
        ){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return headers;
            }
        };

        jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                60000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        jsObjRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jsObjRequest);
    }
```

and JSONObject is as:

```
{
  "subject": "some test value",
  "mailboxId": 170715,
  "type": "email",
  "status": "active",
  "customer": {
    "email": "mymailaddress@mail.com"
  },
  "threads": [
    {
      "type": "customer",
      "text": "some test value",
      "customer": {
        "email": "mymailaddress@mail.com"
      },
      "attachments": [
        {
          "fileName": "Screenshot_20181005-160109.png",
          "mimeType": "image\/png",
          "data": "base64 encoded string goes here"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    "Swytch",
    "Help"
  ]

}
```

Comment: HTTP status 400 is a [bad request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). How are you making your request to the server?

Comment: @Michael, I'm uploading JSON in POST request. This is working on REST API Client (Like: REST API Client). More info: https://developer.helpscout.com/mailbox-api/endpoints/conversations/attachments/delete/

Comment: But how? (i.e. post your Volley code) You're sending a request that is malformed and the server can't parse.

Comment: you should check your web services

Comment: @Michael, I have added required details in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the error just updating the Base64 encoding method as  `Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)` to `Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP)`. With **Base64.DEFAULT** the resulting encoded string is default values for encoder flags (incliding line breaks). **Base64.NO_WRAP** Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line). [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64) is more info.